# autoinstall configuration consistent to GUI?

Tags: 20.04

What's the equivalent of an [Ubuntu server step by step](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/step-by-step) installation with [`autoinstall`](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall)?

An exemplary `user-data` should contain something like:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: my-machine
    password: my-unsecure-secret
    username: my-username
  locale: en_US
  keyboard:
    layout: en
    variant: uk
  ...
```